# Multi Language Translator Project In Python

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am new to python programming language and I am currently learning to code in python. Currently I am developing a project in python named Translator(Multi-Lang) where it will function same as our google translator. I have done half of the project where it would translate text written in any language to another language providing there is a issue with the tkinter where I am not able to enter any text in some other language. Now I am currently working on the Speech to Text module where it would accept speech of the language selected and then display in the textbox.

I am showing the code below. Currently I am stuck in a place where when the user selects the language to be spoken and when he speaks it should automatically get converted in that selected language and then display in the textbox. This I am not able figure out how to do it. Please if anyone can help me out with it ASAP by writing this piece of code it will be really helpful..

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from googletrans import Translator, LANGUAGES
import pyttsx3
import os
import speech_recognition as sr

root=Tk()
root.title("TEXT TO SPEECH")
root.geometry("1280x720")
root.resizable(False,False)
root.configure(bg="#305065")

#Translator_Code

def translate():
    lang_1=sor_txt.get(1.0,END)
    cl=choose_lang.get()

    if lang_1 == '':
        messagebox.showerror("TEXT TO SPEECH","Enter the text to translate!")
    else:
        dest_txt.delete(1.0,END)
        translator=Translator()
        output=translator.translate(lang_1,dest=cl)
        dest_txt.insert('end',output.text)

def clear():
    sor_txt.delete(1.0,'end')
    dest_txt.delete(1.0,'end')



#Frame
frame1=Frame(root,width=1280,height=720,relief=RIDGE,borderwidth=5,bg='#305065')
frame1.place(x=0,y=0)

#Top Text
Label(root,text="TEXT TO SPEECH",font="Helvetica 20 bold",fg="white",bg='#305065').pack(pady=10)

a=tk.StringVar()
auto_select=ttk.Combobox(frame1,width=27,textvariable=a,state='readonly',font=('verdana',10,'bold'))
auto_select['values'] = (

    'Afrikaans',
    'Albanian',
    'Amharic',
    'Arabic',
    'Armenian',
    'Azerbaijani',
    'Basque',
    'Belarusian',
    'Bengali',
    'Bosnian',
    'Bulgarian',
    'Batalan',
    'Cebuano',
    'Chichewa',
    'Chinese (simplified)',
    'Chinese (traditional)',
    'Corsican',
    'Croatian',
    'Czech',
    'Danish',
    'Dutch',
    'English',
    'Esperanto',
    'Estonian',
    'Filipino',
    'Finnish',
    'French',
    'Frisian',
    'Galician',
    'Georgian',
    'German',
    'Greek',
    'Gujarati',
    'Gaitian creole',
    'Hausa',
    'Hawaiian',
    'Hebrew',
    'Hebrew',
    'Hindi',
    'Hmong',
    'Hungarian',
    'Icelandic',
    'Igbo',
    'Indonesian',
    'Irish',
    'Italian',
    'Japanese',
    'Javanese',
    'Kannada',
    'Kazakh',
    'Khmer',
    'Korean',
    'Kurdish (kurmanji)',
    'Kyrgyz',
    'Lao',
    'Latin',
    'Latvian',
    'Lithuanian',
    'Luxembourgish',
    'Macedonian',
    'Malagasy',
    'Malay',
    'Malayalam',
    'Maltese',
    'Maori',
    'Marathi',
    'Mongolian',
    'Myanmar (burmese)',
    'Nepali',
    'Norwegian',
    'Odia',
    'Pashto',
    'Persian',
    'Polish',
    'Portuguese',
    'Punjabi',
    'Romanian',
    'Russian',
    'Samoan',
    'Scots gaelic',
    'Serbian',
    'Sesotho',
    'Shona',
    'Sindhi',
    'Sinhala',
    'Slovak',
    'Slovenian',
    'Somali',
    'Spanish',
    'Sundanese',
    'Swahili',
    'Swedish',
    'Tajik',
    'Tamil',
    'Telugu',
    'Thai',
    'Turkish',
    'Ukrainian',
    'Urdu',
    'Uyghur',
    'Uzbek',
    'Vietnamese',
    'Welsh',
    'Xhosa',
    'Yiddish',
    'Yoruba',
    'Zulu',
    )

auto_select.place(x=150,y=60)
#auto_select.current(0)

l=tk.StringVar()

choose_lang=ttk.Combobox(frame1,width=27,textvariable=l,state='readonly',font=('verdana',10,'bold'))
choose_lang['values'] = (
    'Afrikaans',
    'Albanian',
    'Amharic',
    'Arabic',
    'Armenian',
    'Azerbaijani',
    'Basque',
    'Belarusian',
    'Bengali',
    'Bosnian',
    'Bulgarian',
    'Batalan',
    'Cebuano',
    'Chichewa',
    'Chinese (simplified)',
    'Chinese (traditional)',
    'Corsican',
    'Croatian',
    'Czech',
    'Danish',
    'Dutch',
    'English',
    'Esperanto',
    'Estonian',
    'Filipino',
    'Finnish',
    'French',
    'Frisian',
    'Galician',
    'Georgian',
    'German',
    'Greek',
    'Gujarati',
    'Gaitian creole',
    'Hausa',
    'Hawaiian',
    'Hebrew',
    'Hebrew',
    'Hindi',
    'Hmong',
    'Hungarian',
    'Icelandic',
    'Igbo',
    'Indonesian',
    'Irish',
    'Italian',
    'Japanese',
    'Javanese',
    'Kannada',
    'Kazakh',
    'Khmer',
    'Korean',
    'Kurdish (kurmanji)',
    'Kyrgyz',
    'Lao',
    'Latin',
    'Latvian',
    'Lithuanian',
    'Luxembourgish',
    'Macedonian',
    'Malagasy',
    'Malay',
    'Malayalam',
    'Maltese',
    'Maori',
    'Marathi',
    'Mongolian',
    'Myanmar (burmese)',
    'Nepali',
    'Norwegian',
    'Odia',
    'Pashto',
    'Persian',
    'Polish',
    'Portuguese',
    'Punjabi',
    'Romanian',
    'Russian',
    'Samoan',
    'Scots gaelic',
    'Serbian',
    'Sesotho',
    'Shona',
    'Sindhi',
    'Sinhala',
    'Slovak',
    'Slovenian',
    'Somali',
    'Spanish',
    'Sundanese',
    'Swahili',
    'Swedish',
    'Tajik',
    'Tamil',
    'Telugu',
    'Thai',
    'Turkish',
    'Ukrainian',
    'Urdu',
    'Uyghur',
    'Uzbek',
    'Vietnamese',
    'Welsh',
    'Xhosa',
    'Yiddish',
    'Yoruba',
    'Zulu',

    )

choose_lang.place(x=850,y=60)
#choose_lang.current(0)
               
#icon
image_icon=PhotoImage(file="speak.png")
root.iconphoto(False,image_icon)

#Textboxes & Buttons
sor_txt=Text(frame1,width=40,height=11,borderwidth=5,relief=RIDGE,font=('verdana',15))
sor_txt.place(x=30,y=110)
dest_txt=Text(frame1,width=40,height=11,borderwidth=5,relief=RIDGE,font=('verdana',15))
dest_txt.place(x=710,y=110)

button_change=Button(frame1,text="TRANSLATE",relief=RAISED,borderwidth=2,font=('verdana',10,'bold'),bg='#248aa2',cursor="hand2",command=translate)
button_change.place(x=590,y=430,width=100,height=40)
button_clear=Button(frame1,text="CLEAR",relief=RAISED,borderwidth=2,font=('verdana',10,'bold'),bg='#248aa2',cursor="hand2",command=clear)
button_clear.place(x=590,y=480,width=100,height=40)

#speech to text
def speak():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Speak Anything')
        audio=r.listen(source)
        print('Done!')
        try:
            result = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(result)
        except sr.RequestError:
            exit("API is unreachable")
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            exit("Unable to recognise speech! Were you speaking?")

if (l.get())==('Hindi'):
    sor_text.insert('end',(r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-hi')))


def lang_change(event):
    showinfo(
        title="Result",
        message=f'You selected {a.get()}!'
    )
auto_select.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lang_change)

  
imageicon=PhotoImage(file="speak.png")
speak=Button(root,text="Speak",compound=LEFT,image=imageicon,width=130,font="arial 14 bold",command=speak)
speak.place(x=230,y=430)


root.mainloop()
```

I have separated each module function with headings. The speech to text module is below. I will be asking more doubts on this project in the upcoming days..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you config the language, not lang encoding, you can find the land encoding and use it via: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages